# Rails: Could multiple `around_filter`s cause a database dealock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deadlock

My Rails 3 app has a controller with code like the following (grossly-simplified) example:

```
class DogController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :notify_owner_of_name_change, only: [update]
  around_filter :notify_owner_of_weight_change, only: [update]

  ...

  private

  def notify_owner_of_name_change
    old_name = @dog.name
    yield
    new_name = @dog.name
    @dog.email_owner("Your dog changed its name from #{old_name} to #{new_name}") if old_name != new_name
  end

  def notify_owner_of_weight_change
    old_weight = @dog.weight
    yield
    new_weight = @dog.weight
    @dog.email_owner("Your dog's weight changed from #{old_weight} to #{new_weight}") if old_weight != new_weight
  end
end
```

When a dog's info is updated, it hits the name-change filter, yields to the weight-change filter, yields to the update action, finishes the weight-change filter, then finishes the name-change filter.

Is this pattern likely to cause deadlocks at the database level?